# Saving time only in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery.timepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, timepicker

When I click save, the time I selected in jquery.timepicker plugin is null in ASP.NET MVC sending to server side...
Here it goes when I debug my code and found out that there is no data passed into server side of **StartTime** and **EndTime**..
Here is the screenshot when I debug my code it returns null
[image: debug Code]

Here is my UI where I selected the time
[image: UI Image]

Here is my code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateLeaveApplications(LeaveApplications applications, string Date)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var leavePeriodType = applications.LeavePeriodTypeID;
            LeaveApplications leave = new LeaveApplications();


            if (leavePeriodType == 3)
            {
                leave.StartDate = applications.StartDate;
                leave.EndDate = applications.EndDate;
            }

            else if(leavePeriodType == 2)
            {
                leave.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                leave.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                leave.Cycle = applications.Cycle;
            }

            else if(leavePeriodType == 1)
            {
                leave.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                leave.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                leave.StartTime = applications.StartTime;
                leave.EndTime = applications.EndTime;
            }

            leave.EmployeeID = applications.EmployeeID;
            leave.DateApplied = DateTime.Now;
            leave.LeavePeriodTypeID = applications.LeavePeriodTypeID;
            leave.LeaveTypeID = applications.LeaveTypeID;
            leave.Reason = applications.Reason;
            leave.FirstApproval = applications.FirstApproval;
            leave.SecondApproval = applications.SecondApproval;
            leave.FinalApproval = applications.FinalApproval;
            leave.LeaveStatusID = 1;

            try
            {
                unitOfWork.LeaveApplicationsRepository.Insert(leave);
                unitOfWork.Save();

            }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {

                        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = validationError.PropertyName + " - " + validationError.ErrorMessage });
                    }
                }

            }

            return Json(new { responseText = "Save Successfully", success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        else
        {
            return Json(new { responseText = "Error sending request", success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Try picking up time picker values using `$('#StartTime').val()` and `$('#EndTime').val()` depending on both input's ID, what value you've seen there? Possibly those values are not recognized by `TimeSpan` model binder.

Comment: it will display **8:00 AM** @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: The values need to be `8:00` (8.00 AM) and `20:00` (8.00 PM) to bind (otherwise you would need a custom model binder

Comment: How to make this data to be recognized in TimeSpan ??

Comment: Remove AM/PM components when performing submit or use custom model binder as @StephenMuecke said, because `tt` (AM/PM indicator) format only valid for `DateTime` instance.

Comment: thanks for the information.. It helps me a lot